# I want to get the site information of tk domain in python-whois

Tags: python, python-3.x, whois, tld, pywhois

I want to get the site information of gg domain in python-whois.However, it is not possible to obtain information about a domain in a particular TLD(e.g. example.tk for the tk domain).

```
import whois

res = whois.whois("example.tk")
print(res)
```

```
{
  "domain_name": null,
  "registrar": null,
  "whois_server": null,
  "referral_url": null,
  "updated_date": null,
  "creation_date": null,
  "expiration_date": null,
  "name_servers": null,
  "status": null,
  "emails": null,
  "dnssec": null,
  "name": null,
  "org": null,
  "address": null,
  "city": null,
  "state": null,
  "registrant_postal_code": null,
  "country": null
}
```

I tried specifying a whois.dot.tk server as an argument, but I got an error saying that such a host is unknown.
If you know, please help me.

Comment: `example.tk` isn't registered in their WHOIS database.

Comment: If you use the shell command `whois -h whois.dot.tk example.tk` the response is `The domain you requested is not known in Freenoms database.`

Comment: I suspect they're not maintaining their WHOIS database. I tried a few other names and they aren't know. This isn't your problem, there's nothing you can do about it.